# Really strange error at the very end of a TFS 2015 build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm trying to convert xaml builds to TFS 2015 builds and running into a problem where the build seems to almost complete but then trows the following error:

[image]

And just in case you can't see the image, the error is:

---

Finishing task: VSBuild

---

System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Common.ContextExtensions.GetExpandedPath(ILogServiceContext context, String path, String defaultPathRoot)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.ResolveInputs(IJobContext context, IJobExtension jobExtension, TaskWrapper task, IDictionary`2 variables)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.Run(IJobContext jobContext, IJobRequest job, IJobExtension jobExtension, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
Worker Worker-44f37a2f-ff1b-43a7-b619-88373a8687c0 finished running job 44f37a2f-ff1b-43a7-b619-88373a8687c0

---

Finishing Build

---

It doesn't give me any clues as to where the code is that's causing this error so I really don't know where to look. When I look in the c:\Agent_work\5\a folder it looks like the project is building just fine (although I have no way of verifying that). But all of the files seem to be there including a subdirectory created by an .exe called in the Post-build event on the last .csproj file in the solution which I never even expected to be called and run in TFS 2015! Who knew - that's great! Now if I could just get my build to start working...

Comment: Please don't link to images, just upload them on SO.

Comment: Thanks @DaveShaw - I didn't realize you could do that. I just went back and changed it.

Comment: I would look into the agent logs - it might contain more explicit info about what exact path failed the format validation...

Comment: Did you just mean after  delete or excluded  the .exe called in the Post-build event on the last .csproj file in the solution , there is no error any more. Your build start to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was simply the trailing backslash on the source folder. I had $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)_PublishedWebsites\BOTWSitecoreWeb\ when it should have been $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)_PublishedWebsites\BOTWSitecoreWeb. I just happened to guess this was it - there was no help from the logs.